# In 1982, coin production costs decreased by 1.2 cents/coin. How many coins were produced in 1983? Which statements give information for a solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> In 1982, the production cost of coins decreased by 1.2 cents per coin. How many coins were produced in 1983?
>
> (1) Before 1982, a coin costed 8.8 cents to manufacture. 
> (2) In 1983, $600,000 was saved.
>
> Sufficient information for the solution is obtained ... 
> A. in (1) but not in (2) 
> B. in (2) but not in (1) 
> C. in (1) together with (2) 
> D. in (1) and (2) separately 
> E. not through the two statements

In information (2) it says how much they saved, and in the information prior that they saved 1.2 cents per coin. I then get that 50,000,000 more coins were produced. But I don't know if that answers the question of "how many coins were produced", as we don't have information about the production cost, but only x-1.2 cents/coin.

Comment: Why do you say “$5\times 10^7$ ___more___ coins were produced”? Suppose yesterday you went to restaurant X and bought a few (say, 6) cheesecakes which cost €50 each (sorry, a bit overpriced). You loved them, so next day, you revisited and found that they are offering a discount of €10 per cheesecake. You buy 8 this time. So how much do you save? Do you save €80, or do you save only €30, because only bought 3 ___more___ cheesecakes?

Comment: @insipidintegrator The reason why I say that they are producing 50 million more coins is that we don't know the production cost originally, we only know how much the production cost was decreased by, and how much we saved due to the decrease ($600,000). But to answer your question, we say that we saved €80, if the question is how much we saved at that particular moment. But in your problem we know how much the cake costed each.

Comment: So if the original price was €100 your answer would change from €80?

Comment: @Ericleast992 How would knowing the (previous or new) production cost change your answer to "how many coins were produces in 1983"? What if the production cost before were \$100 per coin? What if the production cost before were just 1.2 cents per coin?

Comment: @insipidintegrator if we suppose that we buy six cheesecakes for €100 each, and we like it very much so the next day we noticed that they offer €10 off discount, so we buy eight of them, and thus we get a profit of €80. We still save the same amount.

Comment: @peterwhy it depends on if we want to know the total production, or the surplus production, i.e. the production amount after there is a decrease in the price of production cost per coin, and the amount of money saved from the total production cost. As it stands, we only know relative prices, i.e. how much the production cost decreased per coin, and the decrease in the production cost (we saved $600,000).

Comment: I see, saving is relative, and maybe our definitions are different. If we buy eight cheesecakes for €90 each today, relative to the purchase of six cheesecakes for €100 each yesterday, we haven't saved but spent €120 more. Would that be like how you consider "surplus production" between years?